# www redirect to non-www is not working despite everything I tried

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all versions of my domain to use https:// non-www version. I've tried many codes on this forum and answers to other similar questions. I use WordPress and DirectAdmin and tried the following:

- Installed a couple of redirection plugins and set the default url to https://non-www
- Created Regex rules
- Added a bunch of codes at the begining of the .htaccess file found online (like the following)
- Used page rules on CloudFlare

Nothing seems to be working.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^salamtavalod.ir$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://salamtavalod.ir/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is crystal clear: I cannot redirect www to non-www version of the URL. The methods I described are not working. I'm looking for a solution to do this.

Comment: Your htaccess rule seems ok. Try to remove any conflicting cause.

Comment: I've emptied all rules from .htaccess file; and also undo everything I tried before. Still not working